# Scroll to top of IFrame when submit the form in iframe

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form which is placed in an IFrame.I have added javascript function for validation. It will rise an error message when click submit button without filling mandatory fields.

The form contains more than 8 fields. The error message will be displayed in top of the page.
So when click the submit button, it stays the bottom of the page. So that, the error message is not visible.

For Scroll to up in an iframe, I have added the following code,

```
parent.parent.window.scroll(0,0);
```

It takes me to the top of the page in iframe.But , Skips the Javascript validation. It passes the request without validation.

Please help me on this one.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Set an id for the error's wrapping div, then use JavaScript's window.location move internally to this id, after - and depending- the mandatory field validation code (you can put it in a conditional statement).
An example on how to use it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <script>
        function scroll(){
          window.location = '#error';
        }
      </script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div id='error'>
        <p>Error: This is an error message.</p>
      </div>
      <iframe src="http://www.yahoo.com" width="400" height="800">
      </iframe>
      </br>
      <input type="button" onclick="scroll()" value="Scroll"></input>
    </body>
  </html>
```

You can also use jQuery to scroll smoothly to it:

http://www.paulund.co.uk/smooth-scroll-to-internal-links-with-jquery